# Enabling LessCSS development mode in Node.js

Tags: css, debugging, node.js, less

I'm having some serious problems finding some LESS parse errors in a large aggregate of CSS.

Error messages are quite useless (at least for me).

My questions are these:

1st. Is there a way to enable more debugging data when parsing LESS inside NodeJS?

2nd. If the existing error block is all that is available, how do you interpret the data? Line numbers do not seem to match up, etc.

For clarification, I am looking at error outputs like this:

```
{ name: 'ParseError',
  message: 'Syntax Error on line 460',
  index: 13409,
  filename: null,
  line: 460,
  column: 0,
  extract: [ '    }', '}', '' ] }
```

At the moment I have several source less files which are arrogated to together in to one piece, then pushed through the parser. So it dies and cut off everything beyond the issue location.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you LESS file contains an error (name or parse error) your LESS code will not compile at all.

Using client side compiling (via less.js) for production and especially if performance is important, will be a bad idea. When using client side compiling for developing and testing your LESS it will be easy to set up debug messages too.

In your case add `<script type="text/javascript">less = { env: 'development' };</script>` tp your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">less = { env: 'development' };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

After doing this your browser will show an error message if you LESS file contains errors:

[image]

More about debugging you will find here: http://lesscss.org/#usage